# Display: none; is not working.

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm a complete beginner trying to create a horizontal drop menu. 
My style sheet doesn't seem to be applying to my submenu level.

Please can you spot the error in my code?

thanks

In my "_SiteLayout.cshtml" I have

```
           <ul id="TopMenu">
                <li><a href="@Href("~/MgtCentre")">Management</a>
                    <ul id=“SubMenu”> 
                        <li><a href="@Href("~/AboutUs")">Admin Centre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Href("~/AboutUs")">Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                 </li>
                <li><a href="@Href("~/FAQ")">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
```

In my "Site.css" I have

```
    ul#SubMenu {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: You dont need to use `ul` infront. just `#SubMenu` is enough

Comment: @Starx unless #SubMenu is defined on another element somewhere!

Comment: @Rippo that would be an error!

Comment: yes if two identical Id's appeared on same page BUT subMenu could  in fact belong to another element on another page! (supposition I know)

Comment: If there is some behavior that you cannot understand, you must act like a computer. With Firebug addon in FF you can inspect your Code. You could have noticed your bad quotes there. You could have typed `document.getElementById('SubMenu')` to find out, it is not there

Comment: #SubMenu could also be defined below site.css, it's the last definition that matters (unless someone is using !important but I digress)

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you have magic/curly quotes in:-

```
ul id=“SubMenu”
```

Should be `"SubMenu"` or `'SubMenu'`

Comment: WOW thank-you!!! I wouldn't have spotted that ever.....I'll beware of it throughout now.

Comment: @Rippo Good one. I totally missed that. How did you find out?

Comment: Must have been my Magic/Curly eyes. :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick tip: I would always recommend installing Firebug and checking all CSS related problems there.

In my opinion, the problem might be:

1. CSS Precedence / Hierarchy
2. Browser Cache issue.

In any case, firebug will easily help you pinpoint the problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In response to the question title, try "!important" as a last resort if nothing else works and you're fighting against CSS you don't have control of, for example when styling a widget or plugin.  In my particular case, !important didn't work which is how I got here.

If !important doesn't work, try variations:

```
<style>

#SubMenu { display:none !important; }
ul#SubMenu { display:none !important; }
#SubMenu * { display:none !important; }
ul#SubMenu * { display:none !important; }

</style>
```

In my particular case, I tried all of these and finally got the desired result:

```
div.gllr_single_image_text { display:none !important; }
.gllr_single_image_text { display:none !important; }
.gllr_single_image_text * { display:none !important; }
div.gllr_single_image_text * { display:none !important; }
```

Strangely, I can't isolate which one of these fixed my problem, testing each individually.  (WordPress or Firefox glitch?)  Regardless, "display:none !important" is useful when you want to clean up something like a 3rd-party widget you have no control of.